# override Date prototype method

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, this, self

I have large arrays of dates in the client, and I want to send them in a JSON string to the server **without a timezone**, that is, I just want to send `2015-04-01` (the client local date) instead of `2015-03-31T16:00:00.000Z`, which is the corresponding UTC date. The simplest way of achieving that seems to me to just override `.toJSON`.

My initial idea was to use [datetime.js](https://github.com/foxbunny/datetimejs) such as:

```
function toJSON(dt) {
    return datetime.strftime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d');
}

Date.prototype.toJSON = toJSON;
```

However, I don't know how to reference `dt` (the instance's *self*) to accomplish that.

Yes, I am thinking in Python still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since toJSON is assigned as the prototype method, `this` will refer to the date inside the method so

```
function toJSON() {
    return datetime.strftime(this, '%Y-%m-%d');
}

Date.prototype.toJSON = toJSON;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need datetime.js for other things, but if you're just using if for this, you might consider a simple function (perhaps attached to *Date.prototype* or given a more meaningful name):

```js
function toJSON(d) {
  
    // Helper for padding
    function pad(n, len) {
      return ('000' + n).slice(-len);
    }
    
    // If not called on a Date instance, or timevalue is NaN, return undefined
    if (isNaN(d) || Object.prototype.toString.call(d) != '[object Date]') return;
    
    // Otherwise, return an ISO format local date string
    return pad(d.getFullYear(), 4) + '-' +
           pad(d.getMonth() + 1, 2) + '-' +
           pad(d.getDate(), 2);
  }

  document.write(toJSON(new Date()));
```

Comment: Yes I am. However this is a nice standalone solution, thanks.